# Previous births of Lava and Kush

Tags: ramayana, rama, rebirth, sita, valmiki

Every jiva has a Purva Janma (previous birth). How about Lava and Kusha's previous birth? Any source which talks about this? Is there any particular reason for their birth?

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=K46QBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA87&ots=iMjbBDNHcl&dq=lava%20kusha%20previous%20birth&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q&f=false) says "They were absolutely human personalities but of very great spiritual heritage from previous births."  I'm not sure if there's a scriptural basis for that though.